# Getting CORS error while connecting to a node js service from ionic framework

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework

I have the below service written in Node js. The service is working fine when accessed individually through browser.

```
     var http = require('http');
     const PORT=8124; 

     var server = http.createServer(function (request, res){
     //res.setHeader(Access-Control-Allow-Origin, *);

     var json = JSON.stringify({
     id : 1,
     message : 'Hurray it worked'
     });

     res.end(json);
     });


    server.listen(PORT, function(){
       console.log("Server listening on: http://localhost:%s", PORT);
    });
```

I am calling the above service from the below ionic application.

```
     angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

     .controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
     $scope.data = {};

     $scope.login = function() {

     $http.post("http://localhost:8124")
        .success(function(data){

            alert("Success");

        })
        .error(function (error){

              alert(error);

           });       
         }
       })
```

I am getting the below error when i run the application.

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8124/. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing)

In order to address the CORS issue, i have added the below line of code

res.setHeader(Access-Control-Allow-Origin, *);

But now service itself is not working.

Is there anything wrong with the code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must surround * with quotes

```
res.setHeader(Access-Control-Allow-Origin, '*');
```

Comment: I would try to take a whitelist approach if this is not a public api

Comment: Jerome, Thanks for replying!! If i add the below line
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

I am getting the below error while running it from the command prompt 

> const PORT=8124;
undefined
> var server = http.createServer(function (request, res){
...    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
... repl.js:296
    top.outputStream.write((e.stack || e) + '\n');

TypeError: Cannot read property 'outputStream' of undefined

Comment: the star is missing `res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '');` -> `res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this Google chrome extension, it solved a lot for me.
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi

Comment: Khaled, Thanks for your reply. But i am using firefox. For some reason, chrome is not working for me!